# Migrating from spaghetti php to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm in the process of moving a PHP project from a spaghetti mess to Laravel. And by Spaghetti I really mean it. The code does not use classes and the PHP files are a mix of HTML and PHP with functions. So far, due to the project being made in PHP 7.1, I cannot use any newer version of Laravel other than 5.8. My initial plan is to get this working alongside Laravel but as-is and only use the Laravel functionality that is required for now (e.g. disabling CSRF check on post forms and adding all endpoints as single routes). Recoding it all from scratch is not possible.

So far I've configured and setup a Laravel Homestead and moved all the projects files into the public folder. I'm facing some issues with global vars inside functions. Theres a lot of functions all around the project php files that uses this to connect to the db like so:

```
function do_something() {
    global $connectionVar
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the `$connectionVar` is null. Its defined in a config file that is included in all the PHP files like so `$connectionVar = mysqli(...);`, but I think that where this `$connectionVar` is defined is no longer considered as being global as it is now run inside laravel.

Can I somehow and/or somewhere define this `$connectionVar` so that it can be used like in the above function without me having to change every single function that uses it?

I've planned to change this to use eloquent at a later point, but right now I want to make it work as it is now with as little influence from Laravel as possible, and then slowly migrate everything piece by piece.

Comment: So what exactly *are* you using Laravel for…?

Comment: In my opinion that will only lead you to more pain. You'll have to migrate twice. I'd just migrate the project little by little to laravel 8 or 9, starting with static pages, then login. If you need to change the data model this is you chance, as long as you have a plan to migrate it to the newer data model without losing any data.

Comment: @deceze Nothing yet.. The idea behind this approach is that I can have part of the project still work on the old code, while creating new stuff with laravel functions and migrate the existing spaghetti code slowly

Comment: But more on topic for your question, laravel does not use mysqli. It uses PDO. To access the PDO instance, you use the DB facade `DB::getPdo()`. Again, I advice to just make a separate project for the laravel "remake" so to speak.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you keep those two things complete separate: a brand spanking new Laravel project, and your old pasta, and configure the divide in your web server, routing specific URLs to one project and the rest to the other. Depending on how you want your URLs to be structured, this can be a pretty clean one-time configuration, or you may need to configure individual paths specifically in more detail. If you use containerisation or any number of other methods, you can even keep your pasta on PHP 7.1 and run Laravel on whatever the latest PHP version is.

Comment: One generally has to define Eloquent models for all the tables and then can conveniently rebuild the application; there is no such thing as "migrating" from sequential to OOP/MVC.

Comment: Sidenote, I thought Spaghetti PHP was a PHP Framework  That being said, I'd have to echo the comments above. I've had to do this exact task before, "migrating" a base PHP project to Laravel, and there is no "simple" way of doing that. Identifying the business logic, determining where existing code goes, optimizing, refactoring and/or rewriting to fit Laravel conventions, etc etc.  are all steps required to complete this. Bonus points if you can keep your existing DB structure as-is and use it with Laravel, but this typically doesn't happen due to missing migrations/columns and what not.

Comment: @TimLewis Spaghetti PHP is a framework made by CopyPaste Inc. and SameCodeEverywhere Ltd.

Comment: @Flame Oh nice! So it's the #1 used PHP Framework worldwide then eh? Love it 

Answer (score -2):

Well, in Laravel, you don't need anymore $connectionVar to connect database. Those settings will be in .env (database connection).

You will need to create all the existing routes of your old website, in routes/web.php

You can replace raw mysql query for Models (app\Models\YourModel.php) but you can use the existent raw query.

Routes are the initial point. Each route will get to a Controller and there you need to create methods. This is the "right" place to put your spaghetti code.

Your HTML, JS, CSS need to put into blades (resources\views\yourBlade.blade.php)

This is an idea.